# Is there a ruby idiom for popping items from an array while a condition is true

Tags: ruby

Is there a Ruby idiom for popping items from an array while a condition is true, and returning the collection?

I.e,

```
# Would pop all negative numbers from the end of 'array' and place them into 'result'.
result = array.pop {|i| i < 0}
```

From what I can tell, something like the above doesn't exist.

I'm currently using

```
result = []
while array.last < 0 do
  result << array.pop
end
```

Comment: More generic; pop all matching items off the end of an array. If a non-matching item is encountered, stop.

Comment: "Don't skip non-matching": I'm having trouble parsing this.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you are looking for [`take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-take_while)?

```
array = [-1, -2, 0, 34, 42, -8, -4]
result = array.reverse.take_while { |x| x < 0 }
```

`result` would be `[-8, -4]`.

To get the original result back you could use `drop_while` instead.

```
result = array.reverse.drop_while { |x| x < 0 }.reverse
```

`result` would be `[-1, -2, 0, 34, 42]` in this case.

Comment: Is there a variant of take_while that also removes the items from array?

Comment: @ComputerLinguist I don't think so unfortunately.  I have looked around on the docs and found nothing.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist, using `drop_while` in the same context above will return your original array with those elements removed.  I.E. `result = [-1, -2, 0, 34, 42]`

Comment: @AGS Thanks for the comment, I just assumed he wanted a new array as he did in the question, but that is a good point if he wants the original back, but it will be in reverse order.

Comment: So ` result = array.reverse!.drop_while {|x| x < 0}; array.reverse!` is as close as we can get, right?

Comment: @ComputerLinguist Yes, I believe so.  Maybe somebody smarter than me can find a solution though :).

Comment: Feel free to update your answer, though - I suspect this as as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it yourself:

```
class Array
  def pop_while(&block)
    result = []
    while not self.empty? and yield(self.last)
      result << self.pop
    end
    return result
  end
end

result = array.pop_while { |i| i < 0 }
```

Comment: True, but but I'm really looking for something more standard/idomatic

Comment: There are the methods `take_while` and `drop_while`, so a `pop_while` looks pretty like it... I'm afraid there isn't something like this in the ruby standard.

Answer (score 0):

In case your looking for a solution to pop all items that satisfy a condition, consider a `select` followed by a `delete_if`, e.g.

```
x = [*-10..10].sample(10)
# [-9, -2, -8, 0, 7, 9, -1, 10, -10, 3]
neg = x.select {|i| i < 0}
# [-9, -2, -8, -1, -10]
pos = x.delete_if {|i| i < 0}
# [0, 7, 9, 10, 3]
# note that `delete_if` modifies x
# so at this point `pos == x`
```